# Why adding noisy predictors improves my random Forest prediction?

Tags: r, random-forest, noise

I am doing some tests with randomForest and I cannot understand the following results :

```
set.seed(12345)
library(caret);library(randomForest)
rmse_vec1<-rmse_vec2<-cor_vec1<-cor_vec2<-c()
for (i in 1:50)
{
  df_train<-data.frame(x1=rnorm(1000),x2=rnorm(1000),x3=rnorm(1000),x4=rnorm(1000))
  df_train$y<-jitter(df_train$x1+df_train$x3,amount=2)

  df_test<-data.frame(x1=rnorm(1000),x2=rnorm(1000),x3=rnorm(1000),x4=rnorm(1000))
  df_test$y<-jitter(df_test$x1+df_test$x3,amount=2)

  rf1<-randomForest(y~x1+x3,df_train) #First model
  p1<-predict(rf1,newdata=df_test)

  rf2<-randomForest(y~x1+x2+x3+x4,df_train) #Second model
  p2<-predict(rf2,newdata=df_test)

  cor_vec1<-c(cor_vec1,cor(p1,df_test$y))
  cor_vec2<-c(cor_vec2,cor(p2,df_test$y))
  rmse_vec1<-c(rmse_vec1,RMSE(p1,df_test$y))
  rmse_vec2<-c(rmse_vec2,RMSE(p2,df_test$y))
}

length(which(cor_vec2>cor_vec1)) # 47
length(which(rmse_vec2<rmse_vec1)) # 42
```

In 94 % (for correlation) and 84 % (for RMSE) of tests, `y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4` is doing better than `y ~ x1 + x3` even if `y <- x1 + x3 + noise` !

Could anyone explain me this result ?

Answer (score -1):

probably because you're diluting your data with normally distributed (same mean and variance I assume) data which has 100% correlation to itself, which it turn improves your total correlation.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Could you elaborate a little on this ? Because it is still unclear to me how it impacts my results.

Comment: I just replaced every rnorm with runif in my code and it does not change anything.

Comment: replace it with rnorm with different mean and variance for each variable, also maybe try increasing the amount of random variables

Comment: Indeed with different mean and var for each predictor `y~x1+x3` is doing better than `y~x1+x2+x3+x4`. But I still dont understand clearly these results.